# Perforce - Find modified/Hijacked Files

Tags: perforce

On Perforce without checking out the files, i modified many files. But now i wanted to see list of all modified files.
I tried using p4 diff -f -sa, p4 changes -m 5 ./.. commands.
I am getting the below error:
**Invalid user (P4USER) or client (P4CLIENT) name.
Purely numeric name not allowed - '123456'.**

Please let me know how to resolve this error and find the list of modified/hijacked files.

Answer (score 1):

Normally the command you'd want to use is "p4 status", but the error you're getting indicates that your P4USER and/or P4CLIENT is set incorrectly, and nothing's going to work until you fix that.  (Your P4USER should be set to your Perforce user name, and your P4CLIENT to the name of the workspace that you synced these files to).  You'll need to double check "p4 info" or "p4 set" and correct whichever it is that's not set correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Just check out your entire branch (might take a few seconds) then revert unchanged files and what's left is all your modified files.